how can we find out normalized bandwidth using two-sided 3db Power spectral density?
If we have the given bandwidth
RF BW = 25e3;
Modulation order M = 8
Modulation index h = 1/4
overlap factor L = 2
 % Create CPM modulator and demodulator with current parameters
            cpmmodulator = comm.CPMModulator('ModulationOrder', M, ...
                'FrequencyPulse', 'Rectangular', ...
                'ModulationIndex', h, ...
                'PulseLength', L, ...
                'BitInput', true, ...
                'SamplesPerSymbol', 8, ...
                'SymbolMapping', 'Gray');

            cpmdemodulator = comm.CPMDemodulator('ModulationOrder', M, ...
                'FrequencyPulse', 'Rectangular', ...
                'ModulationIndex', h, ...
                'PulseLength', L, ...
                'BitOutput', true, ...
                'SamplesPerSymbol', 8, ...
                'SymbolMapping', 'Gray');

            % Generate CPM modulated signal
            modulated_signal = cpmmodulator(bit_stream);

These settings of the modulation scheme
how can we find the normalized bandwidth knowing, that Bnorm completely depends on the variation of M, h, L?
